# Is there a trigger I can use to catch changes to a user's e-mail signature?

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm trying to write an Apex trigger that fires when a user changes his or her e-mail signature through Personal Setup -> Email -> My Email Settings.

Because the signature is stored in `User.Signature`, I thought I could use this:

```
trigger UserTrigger on User (before insert, before update) {
    for (User u : Trigger.new) {
        System.debug('UserTrigger fired for user ' + u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName);
        u.SignatureReference__c = u.Signature;
    }
}
```

Where `SignatureReference__c` is a custom field of type `Long Text Area(1333)`.

It seems that this trigger fires as expected whenever I update a user record through Setup -> Manage Users -> Users, but it doesn't fire when a standard user changes his or her own e-mail signature.

Is there any other object on which I can set a trigger in order to catch this event, or is it simply not possible within the design of Salesforce?

Comment: I've just check std user - it works. trigger usertrigger on User (before insert, before update) {
for (user u: trigger.new)u.signature = u.signature + 'Q';}

Comment: @Ilya That's odd.  I just double-checked myself and am still seeing the dual behavior I reported in the original question: the trigger fires when other fields in the user record are updated, but not when the signature itself is edited directly.  Can you please confirm that you're seeing the trigger fire for you _specifically_ in this situation: change your e-mail signature through Personal Setup -> Email -> My Email Settings?

Comment: confirmed, if I go to My Email Settings, trigger will fire for signature update. check if you have workflow or any other trigger for user obj: http://recordit.co/r8EmHWPqFj

Comment: @IlyaLepesh Checked Setup -> Develop -> Apex Triggers, sorted by Sobject Type, and verified the only trigger on User is my own "UserTrigger".  Did the equivalent for Workflow Rules, and I have no rules that apply to the User object.  Also, I have no Process Builder processes or Flows in my org at all, for what it's worth.  I should also mention I'm getting this behavior in my org's sandbox.  Maybe it's different in production or DE?  What are you testing within?

Comment: just Dev, try to use finest debug

Comment: I set all logging to finest levels and set trace flags on UserTrigger as well as my own user.  No logs at all are generated when I simply edit my signature.  Very detailed logs show if I update my user record through Setup -> Manage Users -> Users.

Comment: please paste your trigger to question

Comment: For what it's worth, I pushed the trigger from sandbox to production, and I still ended up with the same problem in production.